# Error while fetching data from database in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am facing a problem while fetching the data from database

view.php

```
<p>attend</p>
@foreach($attendings as $attending)
@if  ($attending->acceptance==1)
{{ $attending->membername }}
@endif
@endforeach
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<p>not attend</p>
@foreach($attendings as $attending)
@if  ($attending->acceptance==0)
{{ $attending->membername }}
@endif
@endforeach
<br>
<br>
<p>final decision </p>
{{ $attendings->editor_com }}
```

controller

```
public function attendx()
{
       $attendings = DB::table('attendance')->get();
       return view('My_Work.report', ['attendings' => $attendings]);

}
```

routes

```
get('/editor/report','DatabaseController@attendx');
```

But what I'm facing is `Undefined variable: attendings`

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I am writing the codes in laravel 5.1

Comment: Can you delete the `{{ $attendings->editor_com }}` in your view? See if there's any error.

Comment: Noise reduction; Captalization; Clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning **attendings** to this view file **My_Work.report.blade.php**

So you have to place all your code in **report.blade.php** file  .

Remove this line

`{{ $attendings->editor_com }}`

because this will throw error **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: I remove it but still the same error, It didn't change anything